# Need only one match from a Left Join

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello thanks for taking the time to read this.

I have a table TBL_INCIDENT containing columns TXT_INC_ID and TXT_SERVICE, I am using a LEFT JOIN to join it to table TBL_ASMS containing TXT_APPLICATION_ID.  The issue I am having is the join will have multiple matches and I only want the first one.  I saw an example of code using LIMIT 1, but I am unsure syntactically how it is supposed to be used.  I also have seen some solutions for duplication using row_number() over partition, but I could not find one that was a select statement, only deletes.

This is my current state:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.TXT_INC_ID) 
FROM(
    SELECT A.TXT_INC_ID, B.APPLICATION_ID
    FROM TBL_INCIDENT A 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_ASMS B ON A.TXT_SERVICE LIKE ('%' || B.APPLICATION_ID || '%') LIMIT 1
)
```

TXT_INC_ID is the primary key in the table it comes from, and I only want one match per record to be returned by the left join.  I am using left because I need every record in table A returned, but only once.

Thanks

Comment: How do you define the first?

Comment: I meant literally the first one that occurred but I realize that probably isn't meaningful.  Any match is acceptable, is there one method that will execute faster than the other?

Comment: Still interested if anyone has a solution using LIMIT 1 or rownumber() if anyone has the time to demonstrate the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a Max?

```
SELECT COUNT(A.TXT_INC_ID) 
FROM(
    SELECT A.TXT_INC_ID, Max(B.APPLICATION_ID)
    FROM TBL_INCIDENT A 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_ASMS B ON A.TXT_SERVICE LIKE ('%' || B.APPLICATION_ID || '%') 
    group by A.txt_inc_id
)
```

Comment: Would I have to use a group by for every column added to the select in the subquery?  For example:

`SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT A.TXT_INC_ID, A.TXT_SERVICE, Max(B.APPLICATION_ID)
    FROM TBL_INCIDENT A 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_ASMS B ON A.TXT_SERVICE LIKE ('%' || B.APPLICATION_ID || '%') 
    group by A.txt_inc_id, A.TXT_SERVICE
) C`

Answer (score 0):

Your result is logically the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.TXT_INC_ID) 
FROM   TBL_INCIDENT A
```

Comment: It should be, I want 1 record in the result for every record in the left table.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter whether you find a record or not in the joined table, as the count(*) is not affected.

Comment: The joined table has many forms of the same strings, the only constant being a 5 digit substring.  So if I find 12345 in 12345ABC or in 12345ABC-Prod, it relates to the same application in our system, ie it doesnt matter what match I choose, if it had 12345 in it, it will associate to what I need.  The incident ID however needs to stay distinct.

Comment: Whay are you even joining, if the result of the query is the same?

Comment: Ohh sorry answered the wrong question.  "Select Count" was only being used because I needed the result to have the same # of records as the left table.  Now that it is, I have changed it to what I actually want to select.

Comment: The trouble with that approach is that if people do not know what reuslt you *actually* want, then you're not necessarily going to get the best advice on how to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, I get that now.  I was literally looking to make the count the same, but I see now how that isn't really the right question to be asking.